# Android AlertDialog и CheckBox внутри

Tags: java, android, kotlin

В Фрагменте вызываю AlertDialog с CheckBox внутри. Как получить отмеченные там пункты в фрагменте по закрытию ? Массив с ответами есть, а как передать не знаю

Answer (score 2):

```
    val myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null)
    val checkBox = myView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox) as CheckBox
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        // вот здесь можете получить отмеченные пункты
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage("Message")
        .setView(myView)
        .show()
```